# Is it a good idea to handle optional JWT Authentication in Filter?

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt, spring-webflux

I am new to Spring Boot and my current project is a REST API developed in Spring Webflux. The goal is to have an endpoint which has an optional JWT Token, allowing you ti create things anonymously or not. But all the starter guides to Spring Security are really complicated and use Spring MVC, as far as I can tell.

Now my idea was to create a `HandlerFilterFunction` looking like

```
class AuthenticationFilter : HandlerFilterFunction<ServerResponse, ServerResponse> {
    override fun filter(request: ServerRequest, next: HandlerFunction<ServerResponse>): Mono<ServerResponse> {
        val authHeader = request.headers().header("Authorization").firstOrNull()
        // get user from database
        request.attributes()["user"] = user
        return next.handle(request)
    }
}
```

and adding it to the `router {...}` bean.

Is this a good idea, or should I go another router? If so, can somebody point me towards a JWT tutorial for Spring Webflux.

Comment: You might take a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#webflux-oauth2resourceserver-jwt-minimalconfiguration

Answer (score 0):

The [Spring Security docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#webflux-oauth2-resource-server) point to [a JWT-Based WebFlux Resource Server sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/5.2.2.RELEASE/samples/boot/oauth2resourceserver-webflux) in the codebase.

It's not Kotlin-based, so I also posted [a sample of my own](https://github.com/jzheaux/spring-security-kotlin/tree/master/resource-server-jjwt) just now; hopefully, it helps get you started.

As for your question, yes, you can create a filter of your own, though Spring Security ships with a `BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter` that already does what your filter would likely do. The first linked sample adds this filter manually while the second sample lets Spring Boot add it.

Comment: This is too much for my project. I only need a simple JWT authentication without using OAuth.

Comment: What is the framework asking you to do that is too much?

Comment: Oauth requires an oauth provider, which I dont need for this project

Comment: How do you plan to verify the token's correctness? (Perhaps a chat room would be best here, if you are interested.)

Comment: Yeah I would be really interested to chat with you and get a better understanding

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207679/discussion-about-60169199